# Get SHA256 checksum of byte array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Can anybody provide code to get SH256 hash of a byte array in javascript.
i have tried in Crypto.js , but did not get expected output.

Comment: What's the environment? Web page? Node.js? Somewhere else?

Comment: @TanojRout please provide details of your CryptoJS attempt. Thx